# Axios calls not working with localhost in production

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

My title states my problem, but I'm actually looking for a best practice. In the case of my current project I'm using a vue.js app to call out to a nodejs server I have running on the same box. In development I just hardcoded http://localhost/api/etc.... into my axios calls and figured since I was deploying both in production to live on the same box too, that would be fine, but once I deployed I started getting 404s for the axios calls. I had to refactor my code to use the actual dns name of the server.

It works now because of that, but I feel like I'm missing something. I'm not sure if it's a node (for api server) or apache (hosting frontend) issue.

What's the best way to deal with urls?

Comment: I can already envision making my life a little simpler, like creating a url variable so I only have to change in one spot (should have done that in the first place, but was just poking around in this project). But, I still feel like there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually people create a module which exports a custom [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) instance with a `baseUrl`. I think that it is a good practice because you can call the endpoints with the relative `url` only and centralize the api url in a single place as well, making it easier to switch between `development` and `production` urls.

**my-api-client.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const MyApiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

**app.js**

```
import { MyApiClient } from './my-api.js';

MyApiClient.get('my-collection').then(...
```

> If your javascript version doesn't support `import` and `export` statements, you can use `require` and `module.exports` respectively.

Comment: Thanks! I assume the 'my-collection' in the .get call represents the endpoint I want to hit at the baseURL?

Comment: I like this solution, but probably would strip the trailing slash from `baseURL` for clarify, especially if you need to call the `/`.

Comment: @CarltonBrumbelow yes, the `baseUrl` will be prepended to `my-collection` by axios making the full path to your endpoint like `https://some-domain.com/api/my-collection`

Comment: @i-- axios trims forward slashes to combine `baseUrl` with `relativeUrl` so it doesn't really matter.